# Why does the include? method return true in dev and false on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This returns *true* as expected on my dev build, but when deployed to Heroku...returns *false*...same exact data:

```
<% if @squad.team.users.include?(current_user) %>
```

Rails 2.3.8 and MySQL on Amazon RDS.

Anyone run into anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into the [heroku rails console](http://docs.heroku.com/console) and running the same query to be sure that it's actually the same exact data. You might get some helpful output if the `.include?` call is actually failing and not just returning false.

Also, of course, be sure to check your [logs](http://docs.heroku.com/logs-exceptions) to see if anything's failing.

Also, are you sure that you're using the same ruby version in both development and production?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a simple matter to

```
<%= debug @squad.team.users %>
# and
<%= debug current_user %>
```

in your view.